# Why does my C# bubble sort implementation randomly insert blank statements in my leaderboard?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort, leaderboard

So im trying to write a program in c# that reads two files that have 11 names in one and 11 numbers in the other, they're supposed to correspond to a high-score leader board and the users name, i have already got the read and write files part of the code done and it's all fine but the problem comes from my bubble sort (which i have taken from another stack overflow question) and my outputting of the table, every single time i run through it again and have a new users data be input it will put a blank statement with no name and 0 time at the top, every other part of my code works except for this part. If you need more parts of the code i can send more just ask.

```
int[] arr = { 800, 11, 50, 771, 649, 770, 240, 9 };
int temp = 80085;
string tenp = "test";

for (int write = 0; write < highscoreval.Length; write++)
{
    for (int sort = 0; sort < highscoreval.Length - 1; sort++)
    {
        if (highscoreval[sort] > highscoreval[sort + 1])
        {
            temp = highscoreval[sort + 1];
            highscoreval[sort + 1] = highscoreval[sort];
            highscoreval[sort] = temp;

            tenp = highnamestr[sort + 1];
            highnamestr[sort + 1] = highnamestr[sort];
            highnamestr[sort] = tenp;

        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < highscoreval.Length; i++)
    Console.Write(highscoreval[i] + " ");

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Rank || Name || Time");
for (int k = 1; k < length; k++)
{
    Console.Write(k + "    || " + highnamestr[k] + "  ||  " + highscoreval[k]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
            
Console.WriteLine();
```

Ive tried many different ways of outputting the table and sorting the data but nothing seems to be able to get rid of the blank statements appearing

it should output all of the stored data in a nice table and have it all sorted by the end but it usually ends up being sorted and looking nice but having a blank user with 0ms time.

Comment: Why using 2 arrays to store the names and scores when you can create a class and instantiate objects in a single array? That would be simplier and less prone to be buggy

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```cs
for (int k = 1; k < length; k++)
{
    Console.Write(k + "    || " + highnamestr[k] + "  ||  " + highscoreval[k]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Why are you running from 1 to some undefined `length`? The array starts a 0, and apparently you've made it too long and calculated `length` wrong.
The code should be:

```cs
for (int k = 0; k < highnamestr.Length; k++)
{
    Console.Write((k+1) + "    || " + highnamestr[k] + "  ||  " + highscoreval[k]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I've checked it and it works (I set the names to the string version of the score):

```
Rank || Name || Time
1    || 9  ||  9
2    || 11  ||  11
3    || 50  ||  50
4    || 240  ||  240
5    || 649  ||  649
6    || 770  ||  770
7    || 771  ||  771
8    || 800  ||  800
```

But as @Cid suggests, there are more elegant ways of doing this.

Comment: You'll miss the last element using `k < length-1`

Comment: I have no idea what ive done wrong but its still giving me the 0 error even after using your fixed for loop, im checking through the code that deals with reading and writing the files as maybe the error lies there. if you need it i can send the code for the file reading to try help.

Comment: nevermind it was something to do with the reading and writing, something about reading the data and placing it into an array and then passing it to this subroutine caused some errors, ive made it so the files and arrays are defined within this routine and no more 0 error, many thanks Cid and Palle.